# How to link different actions for two Different Buttons Under One Form In php?

Tags: php, database, forms, button, action

What I want is that, I have two buttons in same form. But I want them to post values on pages where they are linked, given that they are linked to two different pages.

If I am unable to explain my problem please refer following codes.

```
<?php

session_start();

echo "<center><table width='75%'>";
echo "<tr><td><div align='left'><h3>Welcome ".$_SESSION['userName']."!</h3></div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='right'><a href='StoreSignOut.php'>Sign Out</a></div></td></tr>";
echo "</table></center>";

include_once('DatabaseConnection.php');

$order=$_POST['store'];
$sql="SELECT * from ".$order;

$query = mysql_query($sql);

if($query)
{
       echo "<br />if ".mysql_error();
}
else
{
       echo "<br />else ".mysql_error();
}

echo "<form method='post' name='myform' id='myform'>";
echo "<center>";

$_SESSION['order']=$order;

echo "Order No. <b>".$order."</b><br />";
echo "<table border='20' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><center>Product Order</center></th>";
echo "<th><center>Quantity</center></th>";
echo "</tr>";

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$result['medname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$result['quantity']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table><br /><br />";

echo "<input type='submit' value='Order Completed' name='submit' id='submit' onclick='myform.action='OrderComplete.php'; return true;')></input>";

echo "<input type='submit' value='Order Given' name='received' id='received' onclick='myform.action='OrderReceived.php'; return true;'></input></center>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

In the line where

```
 echo "<input type='submit' value='Order Completed' name='submit' id='submit' onclick='myform.action='OrderComplete.php'; return true;')></input>";

 echo "<input type='submit' value='Order Given' name='received' id='received' onclick='myform.action='OrderReceived.php'; return true;'></input></center>";
```

These are two buttons. I want them to submit different actions when clicked.

It will be so nice if anyone can help. Thank You...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use only 1 page Order.php with :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //OrderComplete
}
elseif(isset($_POST['received'])){
    //OrderReceived
}
```